# Pass hidden value of a form and retrieve it in thank-you page

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

Is there a solution to get a value to a thank-you page that is not `GET`?

For a marketing and analytical issue, I need to retrieve the **form_id** on the thank-you page of the form from which it comes.

Several forms go to the same thank-you page.

Is it viable for custom.php to launch the thank-you page?

[image]

In addition, Drupal's form settings forces to use one of these redirects
[image]

With `GET` all will be easier, but I don't want to add params in the URL.

Thanks for clarifying me solutions

Comment: What you tried show us the code...

Comment: just add a hidden input to the forms which has thank-you as "action"

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you are trying to achieve exactly, but you could use a session variable as well.

Comment: @jeroen need to retrieve form_id (that i pass as hidden value) in thank-you page so I can add it to javascript datalayer to through to GTM

Comment: @mr.void I'm limited with Drupal's form components don't think I can implement it

Comment: @Qu4k3 how do you retrieve other POST values? retrieving a hidden field is no difference also

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the problem is to retrieve the value of the field in thank-you page while throwing the page, I can not imagine how to get it

Comment: \Drupal::request()->request->get('yourhiddenfield'); ?

Comment: @mr.void nice one, but in the actual model, the thank-you page is displayed with a redirect, so I can't get params

Comment: why you are not using session.Are you using html5?

Comment: @SINGH I didn't know about that possibility, I guess you mean "HTML Web Storage Objects" I'll take a look and try it, thanks

Comment: @Qu4k3 i have added a answer you can go through that.If still you problem not resolved let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try same with two ways.

a. Using session

b. Using LocalStorage

a) Using session when you submit the form.Just store value in you session

```
$_SESSION['form_id'] = 'xyz';
```

In thankyou page you get use it:

```
echo $_SESSION['form_id];
```

Note: Make Sure start your session before set value.

b) Second way is html5 local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("form_id", "xyz");
```

And over thankyou page you can get this value

```
localStorage.getItem("form_id");
```

Comment: Cheers @Qu4k3 :-)